# How to convert a microstation cell library into a format usable in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, style, font, microstation

I am in the process of standardising symbology across CAD and GIS and have decided to use the symbols we currently used for points in microstation. These are stored in a cell library.

Does anyone know how I can create a style or a font out of these cells and therefore use microstation symbols in ArcGIS?

Comment: you have to create a font on the system that matches the cell and use the style manager to control it. can be a very time consuming task.